# "no snap ins have been registered for powershell 4"

Tags: windows, powershell, adfs2.0, skew, pssnapin

I have a `Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard` enabled with `ADFS`. I can open and use `ADFS Management` console. I am not sure which version of `ADFS` is installed on the server. As per Microsoft blogs `Windows Server 2012 R2` comes with `ADFS 2.0`. I donot know how to confirm this.

Now I need to skew the `ADFS` clock by 2 minutes using the powershell `ADFS` snapin.
But when I try giving "get-pssnapin -registered" It doesnot list `ADFS` server.

Can anyone help me on how to execute the below commands on powershell:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Adfs.PowerShell
Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust –identifier “urn:party:sso” | Set –NotBeforeSkew 2
```

Below is the error that I am getting:

```
PS C:\Users\manasa.pandiri> add-pssnapin microsoft.adfs.powershell
add-pssnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 4.
At line:1 char:1
+ add-pssnapin microsoft.adfs.powershell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (microsoft.adfs.powershell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also encountered this issue.  Did a get-module -listavaiable and found that ADFS v1 was present.  Next did a get-command -noun "*ADFS*" and it returned all the ADFS cmdlets.  From there we issues the Set-ADFSRelyingPartTrust and was able to get the notBeforeShew set.